# Sliding Window Pattern

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sliding-window

I am struggling with understanding the this line below:

```
    tempSum = tempSum - arr[i - num] + arr[i]
```

I understand the logic which slides one window everytime. For example, after the first round of iteration which results in 2+1+4 =7, and next iteration by subtracting the first integer "2" from the tempSum and adding the next integer "7" to the tempSum without reiterating all over the number again. However, the issue is **if "tempSum" is equal to 7 in the first round of iteration then why subtract "num" instead of subtracting the first integer of the array "2"**

In my mind, **"num"** is only needed for how long should iteration be, and not for anything else

Please, elaborate on why "num" is being subtracted

```js
function maxSubarraySum(arr, num) {
  let maxSum = 0
  let tempSum = 0
  if (arr.length < num) return null

  for  (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    maxSum += arr[i]
  }
  tempSum = maxSum
  
  for (let i=num; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tempSum = tempSum - arr[i - num] + arr[i]
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, tempSum)
  }

  return maxSum
}

console.log(maxSubarraySum([2,1,4,7,4,5,2,6,4,3], 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nor subtracting `num` from 7. You're subtracting the value in the array at position `i-num`.

```
index    :  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
array arr: [2,1,4,7,4,5,2,6,4,3]
num: 3
```

To print the first value (index 0) in the array `arr` to the console, you can write `console.log(arr[0]);`

That will write `2` to the console.

If you want to print all the values in a loop you can write

```js
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

and that will put

```
2 
1
4
7
4
5
2
6
4
3
```

into the console.

If you want to skip the first `num` elements of the array, instead of `let i = 0` write `let i = num`. So:

```js
for(let i = num; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

and that will output

```
7
4
5
2
6
4
3
```

If you want to access elements relative to the `i`th element, you need to add or subtract from `i`. So if `i` is 5, and you want to access the element at index 9, you'd need to add 4:

```js
console.log(arr[i+4]); 
//outputs 3 if i is 5 because 5+4 is 9 and 3 is at index 9
```

or you want to access the item with the index of 2, then you need to subtract 3:

```js
console.log(arr[i-3]) 
// outputs 4 if i is 5 because 5-3 is 2, and 4 is at index 2
```

Here's a working example you can play with:

```js
const arr = [2,1,4,7,4,5,2,6,4,3];

const idxLbl = document.getElementById('idx');
const rngIdx = document.getElementById('rngIdx');
const offsetLbl = document.getElementById('offset');
const rngOffset = document.getElementById('rngOffset');

let index = 0;
rngIdx.addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
  index = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  idxLbl.textContent = index;
  rngOffset.min = (9-index)-9;
  rngOffset.max = 9 - index;
  rngOffset.value = rngOffset.min;
  offsetLbl.textContent = rngOffset.value;
  offset = parseInt(rngOffset.min, 10);
  updateArrayItemLabel()
});

let offset = 0;
rngOffset.addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
  offset = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  offsetLbl.textContent = offset;
  updateArrayItemLabel();
});

const chosenIndex = document.getElementById('chosenIndex');
const chosenOffset = document.getElementById('chosenOffset');
const arrValue = document.getElementById('arrValue');

function updateArrayItemLabel()
{
  chosenIndex.textContent = index;
  chosenOffset.textContent = offset;
  arrValue.textContent = arr[index+offset];
}
```

```css
body
{
  font-family:sans, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose a starting index: <input type="range" id="rngIdx" value="0" min="0" max="9"> Chosen index:<span id="idx">0</span></p>
<p>Choose an offset: <input type="range" id="rngOffset" value="0" min="0" max="9"> Chosen offset:<span id="offset">0</span></p>
<p>Selectected item: <code>arr[<span id="chosenIndex">0</span>+<span id="chosenOffset">0</span>]</code> is <span id="arrValue">2</span></p>
```

You know that to figure out the next value you subtract the first item outside the window from the sum, and then add the last item inside the window to the sum. The window is `num` elements wide. If `i` is the position of the end of the window, the position of the element to subtract is `num` elements before that. So then the index of the element to subtract is `i-num`, so when `num` is 3 and `i` is 3, the index is 0.

So `tempsum = tempsum - arr[i-num] + arr[i]`, for `num = 3` and `i = num` means `tempsum = tempsum - arr[0] + arr[3]`. Which is what you're expecting.

Comment: ugh... my brain can't just handle it. I am too dumb even for this simple algorithms

Comment: What bit is tripping you up? I'm happy to go into more depth.

Comment: @AkhrorKhamidov I've tried to make things clearer

Comment: I am so grateful for you effort and time to make all of these. Thank you so much. I spent almost 10 hours trying to understand what's going on with arr[i-num]                                   Finally, it clicked. The issue was this, as you said, "The window is num elements wide. If i is the position of the end of the window, the position of the element to subtract is num elements before that"

Answer (score 0):

```html
function maxSubarraySum(arr, num) {
  let maxSum = 0
  let tempSum = 0
  if (arr.length < num) return null


  //first iteration of three integers
  for  (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    maxSum += arr[i]
  }
  tempSum = maxSum

  //second iteration
  for (let i=num; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(tempSum)
    console.log('next iteration')
    console.log(arr[i], "i")
    console.log(num, "num, consider it as index") 
    console.log(`${tempSum} - ${arr[i-num]} + ${arr[i]}`)
    tempSum = tempSum - arr[i - num] + arr[i]
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, tempSum)
  }

  return maxSum
}

console.log(maxSubarraySum([10,50,20,80,30,70,40,10,40,20], 3))
```